# Why does zlib make an effort to compute only a positive pointer difference?

Tags: c, zlib

In zlib 1.2.7, file inffast.c, line 320, there is a statement that I do not understand:

```
strm->avail_out = (unsigned)(out < end ?
                             257 + (end - out) : 257 - (out - end));
```

Variables `end` and `out` are two pointers into the output buffer.
This statement makes an effort to compute `end - out` when `end > out` and `out - end` when `out >= end`, but I do not see why it might want to do that. It seems to me that the end result is the same, that is, the line might as well have been written:

```
strm->avail_out = 257 + (end - out);
```

The difference of two pointers has a signed integral type, `ptrdiff_t` (C99 6.5.6:9), and `257` has type `int`. The addition takes place in the type of higher rank between these two, and I do not see what the ternary operator could possibly be guarding against.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the famous portability of zlib was also made possible by *not* relying on defined behaviour but rather checking what the implementations actually do.

Comment: Is there a source code repo with enough history to blame this line and see if it evolved from a different formulation?

Comment: @Potatoswatter The only thing I found is in the “Change history” in inflate.c “Change strm->next_out[-state->offset] to *(strm->next_out - state->offset) to avoid negation problem on Alphas (64 bit) in inflate.c” but that does not explain it. I can see how `p[-o]` could be different from `*(p-o)` with `o` a 32-bit unsigned int and `p` a 64-bit pointer. The statement in my question is something else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your observation is correct for C99 as well as C89/C90.

That line of code was written ten years ago.  At this point my memory permits me only to be able to claim paranoia as the excuse.  Apparently I was concerned that in some compilers the result of subtracting two pointers might be unsigned.  I do not recall the origin of that concern, or if it had any basis at all.

As for the [change history](https://github.com/madler/zlib/), that line of code was born from the brow of Zeus as you see it today.  It has not been changed since it was written.